# I can't get the final statement to print when entering 'n'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a problem that used a dictionary to store states and capitals and then ask the user to play a quiz. When the state is randomly displayed the user is supposed to enter the capital. The user is notified if they are correct or not. Then the user is asked to play again. When entering 'n' its supposed to stop and give you the number of correct and incorrect answers. But the loop keeps playing when entering 'n' and I can't get the the last statement to execute. thanks in advance. 
For brevity not all the states and capitals are shown.

```
def main():
    states_caps = {'Alabama' : 'Montgomery' ,'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Pheonix',  'Arkansas':   'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento','Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}

    print('Welcome to the Capitals of States quiz!')
    PlayAgain = "Y"
    correct_answer = 0
    incorrect_answer = 0
    while (PlayAgain =="Y"):
       for key in states_caps:
         print('\nThe state is:', key)
         capital = input('\nWhat is the capital?  ')
         if capital  == states_caps.get(key):
           print('You are correct!!')
           correct_answer +=1
         else:
           print('\nSorry, that is not correct.')
           print('The correct answer is,' , states_caps.get(key))
           incorrect_answer +=1
        PlayAgain = input("\nPlay again? (Y/N) ").upper()

    print('\nYou had', correct_answer, 'correct answers and',  incorrect_answer, 'incorrect answers.')

main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is *very inconsistent*. I fixed the first two lines then indented the whole codeblock with the editor (using the `{}` key) but you probably need to post the code again yourself. Select the code after posting and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format the code. As posted, the code won't run.

Comment: I copied and pasted and obvious this caused the problem. On future questions I'll do better. Thanks Martijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it's because you loop over all the states *before* asking the user whether they want to play again. One solution is below (loop over the keys and break if the user answers N to "Play Again"?

```
def main():
    states_caps = {'Alabama' : 'Montgomery' ,'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Pheonix',  'Arkansas':   'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento','Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}

    print('Welcome to the Capitals of States quiz!')
    PlayAgain = "Y"
    correct_answer = 0
    incorrect_answer = 0
    states = list(states_caps.keys())
    for state in states:
        print('\nThe state is:', state)
        capital = input('\nWhat is the capital?  ')
        if capital  == states_caps.get(state):
            print('You are correct!!')
            correct_answer +=1
        else:
            print('\nSorry, that is not correct.')
            print('The correct answer is,' , states_caps.get(state))
            incorrect_answer +=1
        PlayAgain = input("\nPlay again? (Y/N) ").upper()
        if PlayAgain == 'N':
            break


    print('\nYou had', correct_answer, 'correct answers and',  incorrect_answer, 'incorrect answers.')

main()
```

Comment: Thanks xnx. One thing that I would like to do is to go through all the states once. I notice that this just loops back through the list after the PlayAgain. I tried states_cap.pop(key) but if I gave the wrong answer the correct answer was not printed in the else statement using the .get(key) or .pop(key) it gave me "None".

Comment: OK - updated. `pop`ping the key removes the entry from the dictionary which is why you couldn't retrieve it to give the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the for loop but didn't get the correct order of operations.

Comment: Feel free to hit the big green check-mark if this has answered your question :)